# hash<std::string> vs hash<std::string_view>

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

C++17 introduced [`hash<string_view>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/hash). When writing my own custom hashes I want to reuse the STL implementation of the string hash.

Is `std::hash<std::string>()("Hello, world")` slower than `std::hash<std::string_view>()("Hello, world")`? Is it the same?

When do I ever want to use `std::hash<std::string>()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::hash<std::string>` takes a `std::string const&` as the parameter for its `operator()`.  If you have `std::string`'s, and you are hashing them, then this what you want.  If you use `hash<string_view>` then it is going to have to convert the `std::string` into a `std::string_view`, which has some cost to it (not much, but it is there).

If your data set doesn't contain just `std::string`s but also contains c-strings, then `hash<string_view>` can be better.  converting a c-string into a `std::string` can require dynamic memory allocation so if you can avoid that normally you win in the performance area.  This needs profiling though since the mix of `std::string`s and c-strings matter as well as the size of the c-strings as SSO (short string optimization) may make `std::hash<std::string>` the better choice.

Comment: I like this answer more. @eerorika said "Former is slower because creating a std::string is slower than creating a std::string_view", and I don't see why computing a hash of an std::string implies copying it - it just takes it by reference and operates on it, as you said.

Comment: @Valentin Do note that eerorika is correct that `std::hash<std::string>()("Hello, world")` is slower than `std::hash<std::string_view>()("Hello, world")` since it will have to create a `std::string` first.

Answer (score 3):

> Is `std::hash<std::string>()("Hello, world")` slower than `std::hash<std::string_view>()("Hello, world")`?

Yes.

Former is slower because creating a `std::string` is slower than creating a `std::string_view`.

> When do I ever want to use `std::hash<std::string>()`?

When you have a `std::string` object and you want to calculate a hash value from it.

Comment: why wouldn't I use `std::hash<std::string_view>()(myStr.c_str())` in the second case?

Comment: @Valentin because that's unnecessary, more complicated, and potentially slower.

Comment: @Valentin `std::hash<std::string>` is slower *when hashing a literal* because a copy of the string has to be made. It's not slower when hashing a `std::string`.

Comment: @Valentin: Generally speaking, you're usually not directly asking for a hash. You're typically using a container like `unordered_map`, which itself asks for hashes. If you need an `unordered_map<string, T>`, because it needs to own the storage for the keys, then it will use `hash<string>` rather than `string_view`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would a compiler theoretically be allowed to apply heap ellision in the `std::string` scenario here when passing a string literal?

Comment: @Frank sure. Small string optimisation is quite common and `"Hello, world"` probably is small enough.